# Which class is best suited for a ME3 Insanity playthrough?

Tags: mass-effect-3

As per the title.
What would be the easiest to play?

Comment: Well Vanguard is pretty risky as being up close can get you killed, I know that much. Still not impossible.

Comment: I removed the part of your question asking for a users personal preferences. We don't allow questions like that on our site since they are both subjective, and are more of a discussion than a Q&A. You should take the time to read our [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: I would say the whole question is asking for an opinion which is not allowed, but since I don't actually agree with the rules I am going to give this +1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that there will be a lot a personal preference involved in any answer you get.  Play style will have a big impact on what works best for you.

I haven't played all of the classes in ME3 yet, but I would suggest Infiltrator.  They have really good damage output, and tactical cloak is very useful.

You can engage enemies from far range, which favors you.  Cloak can get you out of tough spots and away from dangerous melee based enemies.  The Incinerate ability is not quite as useful in ME3 as in ME2, but is still a good all-around tech power.

You will need to use party members that give access to Warp and Overload to make sure you can handle all enemies effectively.

Comment: along with the black widow and concentration mod

Comment: I second the infiltrator.  Make sure you pick up energy drain as the bonus power, it is a great way of removing shields AND barriers, recharging yours, not to mention heavy damage on mechs such as atlas and any geth.  For squad members, liara (bio explosion), tali (drones), and garrus/ashley(mines/grenades) are also great choices.

Comment: Personal play style preferences are a huge factor.  Each class will dovetail nicely with certain play styles.

Answer (score 2):

Played all classes in insanity, the easiest for me was the vanguard by reducing cooldown at max with armor cooldown + 200% + reducing powers cooldown... Also you can earn how to use nova to never get hit. When you see a banshee shooting you, you have just to do a nova to block all damage because nova give you immortal during animation.

After this, the enginer is very powerfull, I killed 10 banshee in last map on earth before I go on lauching rockets. Helped by Tali and James. This is because I wanted to test if they has infinite respawn. I used Tali for his sabotage and full armored drone. Same for me sabotage and full armored drone. James become get a full armor build, play at melee in first line with drones supports while Tali and me are spamming sabotage, drain, incinerate, ..

The other best classe is adept because you can do easy 3 combo in one row. By example is to use sabotage(1.5s) or overload + incinerate or carnage + warp + throw. In this case you do a tech burst + a fire explosion + a full biotic explosion (+100%) all in one row. If you learn how to sync your shoots and the pattern you can insta kill a banshee.

other classes are more classics.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have preference (i.e. you do not prefer to shoot a lot for example) - I would suggest going Sentinel. For me personally this is THE best single player class in the game (Mass Effect 2 included). You get both Overload and Wrap (important for taking down shield & barrier), Tech Armor for defense (really important, especially in ME2), and then finally - Throw (hello my auto-targeting weapon replacement).

Once you have all 4 setup and both Javik (DLC required) and Liara are in your team it's extremely easy to play:

1. Take cover and stay in cover
2. Take down Shield / Barrier / Armor with Overload / Wrap
3. Singulary or Pull
4. Throw

With Javik & Liara reduce cooldown abilities + upgrading your own abilities with cooldown reduction, you'll get to the point where you can Throw almost every second... and you'll mostly use that to detonate opponents which you previously lift with Liara's Singulary / Javik's Pull.

You may run into two problems:

1. Until you level up all 4 mentioned abilities, you may have problems with opponents overwhelming your covered position. Hardest part of the game for me was the begging actually ;) So, concentrate on upgrading said 4 abilities (Tech Armor is lowest priority since you can just activate it and leave it on) and once you can activate your powers really quickly, it'll be much easier.
2. Opponents with Armor may be hard to take down with this setup initially. However, you can deal with this in numerous ways:

   - Liara has Wrap Ammo skill that you want to level up regardless of Armor into Squad power. It won't help too much against Armored opponents, but it'll help.
   - Take armor piercing on your weapons, you won't be using them much on other targets anyway
   - Take someone else instead of Javik (I love Liara for Singularity, but you can use Javik - just make sure he has Pull Field unlocked for Guardians). Vega is good replacement - he has Incendiary Ammo + Carnage and lots of health.
   - When you level up enough, you can take Carnage/Reave as a bonus skill.